# How to implement Webcam effects?

Tags: video-processing

And now for some fun... I'd like to reproduce the technology behind Logitech Video Effects as seen here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qZLgA2g7Ow4

How do they track the user's head, eyes and mouth (in read-time no less)? Are there any publications on the algorithms behind this technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using a "computer vision" library such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)